# Why do site seals use document.write?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

When including a site seal on a website, it seems like they always want to use an inline script that alters the DOM with document.write and holds up the page load until it is finished. Most of the time, these seals load quickly, but sometimes, and not always rarely, they take several seconds to load. In the meantime, everything else on the site politely sitting in document.ready methods don't run and the page looks odd and/or doesn't function correctly until then. These seals are buried in the footer because they should be seen only by people looking for them. They should always run last.

I know there are ways to mitigate that (iframes or overwriting document.write if nothing else uses it), but my question is why do site seals do this at all? Isn't there a better way?

Are they just trying to be incredibly simplistic in what people include, so they can't have an anchor tag wrapped around an image linked to a script? People just copy/paste the code given to them.

Maybe it gives them more control to change the design/functionality of the seal's wrapper without having clients update their sites?

It's just a usability headache that seems so prevalent and I don't understand why. Is there some security thing I'm overlooking? Like a script needs to be running natively to be able to verify the domain?

Comment: They're just being lazy as it lets them write _HTML_ directly. If they offer no alternatives and you have to use them, there is little you can do. Well, you could shadow `document.write` and implement a friendly alternative because it's a horrible function, but they may not be happy.

Comment: What exactly is a "site seal"? A logo?

Comment: these "seals" are just images with anchor like `<a href="#"><img /></a>`. just copy html instead including `<script>`. Trust me, none of your visitors cared is it `<script>` or html copied by yourself

Comment: Googling "site seal" brings up a plethora of examples, but it's basically an image and link that a third party provides to offer some semblance of "security" to people that don't otherwise know you. Users trust a name like Norton or McAffe more than random small internet companies, and those large companies vet smaller ones and offer secure seals or SSL certificates. Does it mean anything? Probably not, but that doesn't mean they're not useful to some people, especially if your small business has clients that are less internet-savvy.

Comment: While I haven't checked, I assume that pulling out the HTML the script generates and embedding that in the page directly violates the terms of using the seal in the first place.